# How many integer-valued solutions are there?

Tags: combinatorics

How many integer-valued solutions are there?

$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 \le 63, \qquad \forall i,\,x_i > 0 $$

My approach:

I think it's "Stars and Bars" Problem. So, when the sum is $63$, we have $63+5-1 \choose 5-1$ = $68 \choose 4$.

And if the sum is $62$, it's $67 \choose 4$.

So the integer-valued solutions are...
$$ {68 \choose 4} + {67 \choose 4}  + \cdots + {5 \choose 4} + {4 \choose 4}$$
Uhmm am I right...?? I think the answer should be a simple combinatorial function like... ${69\choose 5}$.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $$63+5-1\neq 68$$

Comment: That's not claimed, @WeijunZhou.

Comment: @Shaun He wrote (63+5-1) choose (5-1) = 68 choose 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, you mean *nonnegative* integer-valued solutions.

It can be done in one shot, using a dummy variable $x_6$ to take up the slack.

Explicitly, the number of $5$-tuples $(x_1,...,x_5)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying
$$x_1 + \cdots + x_5 \le 63$$
is the same as the number of  $6$-tuples $(x_1,...,x_6)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying
$$x_1 + \cdots + x_5 + x_6 = 63$$
Finish by using the stars-and-bars formula to count the number of nonnegative integer solutions to the above equation.

Comment: This is very good idea. Could you explain more ???

Comment: please elaborate little bit more how adding $$x_6 is same as ...

Comment: For every $5$-tuple $(x_1,...,x_5)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying the inequality, there is a uniquely determined nonnegative integer $x_6$ which converts the inequality into an equality. Conversely, for every $6$-tuple $(x_1,...,x_6)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying the equality, the $5$-tuple $(x_1,...,x_5)$ satisfies the inequality, and is uniquely determined by $(x_1,...,x_6)$.

Comment: Here is the follow up question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625998/how-many-integer-valued-solutions-are-there

Comment: If only _positive_ integer solutions are desired, then this problem is equivalent to finding the number of positive integer solutions of $x_1+\dots+x_6=64$, so that $x_6>0$ as well. In this case, the number of solutions would be $\binom{64-1}{6-1}=\binom{63}{5}$.